# Why does the Python runtime coerce the return of "in" to bool, but not the result of comparison operators (==, >, <, etc)?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, symbolic-computation

Consider the following class definition:

```
class Symbolic(object):
    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return Symbolic()
    def __le__(self, rhs):
        return Symbolic()
    def __gt__(self, rhs):
        return Symbolic()
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return Symbolic()
```

The operations defined on the class behave like so:

```
x = Symbolic()
y = Symbolic()

x == y    -->   <Symbolic object at ...>
x <= y    -->   <Symbolic object at ...>
x > y     -->   <Symbolic object at ...>
y in x    -->   True  # huh?
```

As per the title, my question is: why does the Python runtime explicitly coerce the output of the `in` operator to a boolean type, but not the output of other comparison operators which are expected to return a boolean value (`==`, `<=`, `>`, etc)?

**EDIT:** The docs say the following about the `in` operator and rich comparisons respectively:

- > For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` is true if and only if `y.__contains__(x)` is true.
- > By convention, False and True are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call bool() on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

The question still stands: why is the distinction necessary?

Comment: The duplicate that is marked seems to be about using a list for the second argument of `in`, which doesn't seem to be the case in this question.

Comment: Related: [Python-ideas: Non-boolean return from `__contains__`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-July/007733.html)

Comment: My guess is that the rich comparison operators were introduced in a more lenient time (Python 2.1), while `__contains__` was introduced later (the docs don't mention when it was introduced); and if it weren't for backwards-compatibility concerns, the rich comparison operators would also be required to return Boolean values.

Comment: @martijn-pieters, the duplicate question only says "you can't", it does not address the reason behind *why* `in` behaves differently to rich comparisons when they are almost universally used in the same manner and context.

Comment: Right, and undefined points you to the answer: `__contains__` is different because it operates on the *right-hand operand* as opposed to the left and there is no corresponding inverse hook. In that at least it is consistent  with `__bool__` and `not`. The Python ideas discussion showed there was no proper usecase to change the behaviour.